# Same values with different pointers in a linked list?

Tags: c, for-loop, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

Why does this code output the same name for all the nodes in the linked list?

Program output

```
Insert number of users : 
4
Mike
John
Bob
Alice
Name : Alice @ Pointer :0x874ae0 
Name : Alice @ Pointer :0x874b00 
Name : Alice @ Pointer :0x874b20 
Name : Alice @ Pointer :(nil)
```

The idea behind this code is to take `x` number of user names and create a linked list then loop over the linked list and print each name with the pointer for the next name.

```
typedef struct node
{
    char *name;
    struct node *next;
} node;

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    printf("Insert number of users :\n"); // capture int from user
    scanf("%i", &x);

    char str[LENGTH];

    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n == NULL)
        return 1;

    node *start = n; // pointer to the start of the linked list

    // loop for n times to capture names 
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", str); // capture string 
        
        n->name = str;
        // reached end of loop
        if (i == x-1)
            n->next = NULL;
        else 
            n->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
        n = n->next;
    }

    for (node *tmp = start; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
    {
        printf("Name : %s @ Pointer :%p\n", tmp->name, tmp->next);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A simple script to take the names of people and insert them into a linked list.

Comment: `n->name = str;` - this assigns the same `str` to all the nodes. You need to allocate new memory for each one

Comment: `n->name = str;` --> `n->name = strdup(str);`

Comment: Do never use `scanf("%s",str);` NEVER. You risk buffer overflows by not limiting the input string length and you don't check the return value, which would also cause UB when `scanf()` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement within the for loop

```
n->name = str;
```

the data member name of all nodes is set to the address of the first character of the array str declared like

```
char str[LENGTH];
```

So all nodes will point to the same array — that is, to the last stored string in this array after the `for` loop.

You need to create dynamically a copy of the string stored in the array for each node. Something like

```
#include <string.h>

//...

n->name = malloc( strlen( str ) + 1 );
strcpy( n->name, str );
```

Comment: I would suggest `strdup` for that. It's also in `strings.h` and pretty standard. Effectively that does exactly the same, so it should be noted that the memory should be freed after use (in both cases).

Comment: @Cheatah Using `char *str=NULL; int r=scanf("%ms",&str);` could be better on system where the `m` options is supported, this way the OP would get rid of his buffer overflow problem too.